# Magento : Create admin module

Tags: magento

I have a problem. I following guideline but it doesn't work. I don't know debug how. Please tell me the way resolve problem.

This is HS_Imagepro.xml in etc/modules/ folder

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config>
   <modules>
    <HS_Imagepro>
            <active>True</active>
            <codePool>core</codePool>
    </HS_Imagepro>
   </modules>
</config>
```

This is config.xml in HS/Imagepro/etc folder

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config>
  <modules>
    <HS_Imagepro>
        <version>0.1.1</version>
    </HS_Imagepro>
</modules>
  <admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <module>HS_Imagepro</module>
                    <frontName>imagepro</frontName>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
  </admin>
  <adminhtml>
    <menu>
        <imagepro_menu translate="title" module="imagepro">
            <title>ImagePro</title> 
            <sort_order>9999</sort_order>
            <children>
                <first_page module="imagepro">
                    <title>Our First Page</title> 
                    <action>imagepro/index/index</action>
                </first_page>
            </children>
        </imagepro_menu>
    </menu> 
</adminhtml>
<global>
<helpers>
    <imagepro>
        <class>HS_Imagepro_Helper</class>
    </imagepro>
    </helpers>
</global> 
</config>
```

This is IndexController.php in HS/Imagepro/controllers/

```
<?php
 class HS_Imagepro_IndexController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
 {
public function indexAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->renderLayout();
}
}
?>
```

The result is the page not found.
If The following right guideline, access link `http://localhost/magento/index.php/imagepro/` will appear admin login screen.

Comment: Don't use the `core` codepool. Use community or local instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ,HS_Imagepro.xml file the `test TRUE Should be true`.

routing code Wrong  in config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config>
  <modules>
    <HS_Imagepro>
        <version>0.1.1</version>
    </HS_Imagepro>
</modules>
<admin>
        <routers>
            <!-- Includes our controller, so when we add the adminhtml menu item below, it is found! -->
            <adminhtml>
                 <args>
                     <modules>
                         <imagepro before="Mage_Adminhtml">HS_Imagepro_Adminhtml</imagepro>
                     </modules>
                 </args>
             </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

Also controller file and path name is wrong
HS/Imagepro/controllers/Adminhtml/ImageproController.php

```
<?php
 class HS_Imagepro_Adminhtml_ImageproController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
 {
public function indexAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->renderLayout();
}
}
?>
```

Testing url yourhost/magento/index.php/admin/imagepro

More details on http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/custom_module_with_custom_database_table#directory_additions

and frontend module http://www.amitbera.com/create-an-magento-extension-with-custom-database-table/

Comment: Thanks a lot. But when I can't access http://localhost/myproject/imagepro/. I don't know when I access this link, magento will process how.

Comment: Okay. I did. Thanks a lot of your clear explanation.